# Is there any way to reattach to a screen session that's in a loop?

Tags: linux, cygwin, gnu-screen

Technically, I'm using Cygwin to run screen on Windows if it matters.

Say I have a simple loop running. Like "Enter a number, if it's not zero, loop back and enter another number." and I want to run that using screen and then disconnect, reconnect, and keep entering numbers. Is that possible? Right now, if the screen is in a loop or another program when I lose connection(mostly internet issues), then it just tells me that the session is `(Dead ???)` in the `screen -ls` list and I can't reconnect to it.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. One the main benefits of screen is that the state of the virtual session is maintained when you disconnect, no matter what program is running in it.

Comment: But maybe Cygwin can't emulate this ability of real Unix.

Comment: Sorry about that! I thought this was okay to ask here!

Yeah, I have no idea. For whatever reason, it's unable to reach any screen that's stuck in a loop.